# Make virtual attribute listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to make my virtual attribute listed. I have a virtual attribute `attr_accessor :damage` and callback `after_find` that populate that attribute with some value. So how can i make that attribute listed in `@user` variable, so i can pass that variable to front-end (using `react-rails` gem) and use it like object property with javascript?

Comment: If you have an `attr_accessor` it will be exposed. Are you asking how you can get this to show up in the output of `to_json`?

Comment: @tadman Yes. Also, when i'm doing something like `@user.inspect`, i can't see it either

Comment: I'd either make it an actual column and forget about the cost or go through the trouble of overriding `inspect` and `as_json` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to explicitly define method (accessors) like so:

```
@user.to_json(methods: [:damage])
```